# How to remove error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file is not computed

Tags: react-native

[image]I've tried to connect mysql with my react-navtive app. I install express, body-parser and mysql also then I create server.js in my project and type "node server.js" cmd on terminal then I get this error

```
error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js) is not computed
```

I don't know what is this and how to solve this error please help me with this error...

Note: I'm using ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your react-native-cli version?

Perhaps, update the react-native-cli:

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: I'm using version 4.10.1 but still experiencing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try running using this

```
npm run start --reset-cache OR react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it twas the fact that I had a `.` in my directory folder so `example.com` to `examplecom` had fixed the issue for me